# Keyboard cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Im a newbie on Java. I get an error. These are my simple codes:

```
public class AreaRect {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int height, width, area;
        System.out.print("yukseklik?");
        height = Keyboard.readInt();
        System.out.print("genislik?");
        width = Keyboard.readInt();
        area = height * width;
        System.out.print(area);

    }

}
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Keyboard cannot be resolved
    Keyboard cannot be resolved

    at AreaRect.main(AreaRect.java:8)
```

I have a Keyboard.class file in the same directory with AreaRect.java..
Please can you tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you importing the file with your Keyboard class?

Comment: `import package1.package2.package3.ClassName;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize your files into [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/).

Move both Java files to a folder, e.g., `mypackage`. Then, add the following line to the top of each file:

```
package mypackage;
```

You can also have subpackages with nested folders. For example, the folder structure:

```
com
  example
    mypkg
      AreaRect.java
      Keyboard.java
```

could use the package `com.example.mypkg`.

Answer (score 0):

If you  are trying to compile your class via commandline with `javac AreaRect.java`, it will work to have the Keyboard.class file in the same folder.
If you are however trying to run this in Eclipse, it won't work until you add the .class file to a seperate folder and then add said folder to your buildpath via "Properties->Java Build Path->Add Class Folder".

Comment: What did not work? Are you using the javac approach or Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I downloaded this file http://duke.csc.villanova.edu/jss1/bookResources/keyboardDownloads/Keyboard.java  and put it in same folder with my AreaRect.java file. I am getting this error:                                           in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at Keyboard.readInt(Keyboard.java:244)
 at AreaRect.main(AreaRect.java:8)

Comment: Yes that's why I put the seperate procedure for Eclipse into my answer.. Place the .class file into a new folder in your Eclipse project (NOT your source folder), and then add said folder to your buildpath as a Class Folder (see answer above for instructions).

Comment: I did. I have a folder in my java project. I added this folder from buildpath- Add Class Folder. And I put my Keyboard.class file in this folder. But still get error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Keyboard cannot be resolved

 at AreaRect.main(AreaRect.java:8)
:((((

Comment: Just had a look at the file you provided. There is a package declaration at the top. In your case you can just delete the line `package cs1;`. And as it is a .java file you don't need to do anything fancy with the Class Folder. Just put the Keyboard.java file next to your own .java file, remove the line I mentioned earlier, refresh the project in Eclipse and that's it.

Comment: Yea I did and I understood but still have an error. I have (!) this in front of project. But this (x) has gone. And error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Keyboard cannot be resolved

 at AreaRect.main(AreaRect.java:8)
I am so sorry :(

Comment: Well as you are using Eclipse: Eclipse has the nifty Problems view which a) displays problems and b) offers advice on what to do about them. No need to try and run your program for that. What does the Problems view say?

Comment: Marco thank you very much, I am not getting error anymore. I  appreciate to your helpings :)